# Can't change MySQL/MariaDB server collation option

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to change the server's `collation_server` variable default option from *latin1_swedish_ci* to *utf8_general_ci* by adding it into the `/etc/my.cnf.d/mariadb-server.cnf` config file under a different group on each try, but it just won't work. When I try to restart the daemon it always fails unless I comment it out or remove the line. How can I change this variable so it's also persistent across restarts?

I have read how to accomplish this on the official reference pages on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_collation-server and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html but they were of no help for me.

Thank you.

Comment: Login to Linux shell and run the following : `mysqld --help --verbose 2>/dev/null | grep my | grep cnf | head -1`. What is the output ???

Comment: The output is `/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf` but I ran `mysql` instead of `mysqld`.

Comment: Please run `mysqld --help --verbose 2>/dev/null | grep my | grep cnf | head -1` as I first mentioned. What's the output ??? (I specified mysqld because you said you are trying to change the server's collation_server).

Comment: Using mysqld instead of mysql: nothing. Because mysqld is not a command.

Comment: Yes, it is most definitely a command. (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqld.html) mysqld is the server process. It is a command you can run on the command line to see options. mysqld will not allow two server daemons on the same data. Once it is doing so, you can `mysqld --help --verbose` like the documentation says (which I have done for years)

Comment: Question: Are you trying to change the server collation on a remote server ???

Comment: Yes, but the server is mine and it's a VPS. Nevermind I've managed to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to finally solve this. By looking at the logs I noticed an error saying that `'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'` and by googling a little, the solution was in [this post in a blog](https://lalitvc.wordpress.com/2014/10/17/error-collation-utf8_general_ci-is-not-valid-for-character-set-latin1/), quoting:

> In this case mysqld trying to start  with  character-set-server = latin1 and collation-server = utf8_general_ci, which is not valid.

So the solution is to set a either a valid latin1 collation or change the server's character set, which I did:

```
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
```

On my cnf file (*/etc/my.cnf.d/mariadb-server.cnf*) under the `[server]` block. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your comments I hope this helps somebody else too.